# How can I add a counter for every miss the user makes?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble counting the amount of times the user makes a wrong input in my hangman game. The strategy I tried was to count within the for loop that checks if the guess is correct, but since I'm checking a character array through a loop the counter adds 1 every single iteration of the for loop instead of every time there is a wrong input. SOS this is for school

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        String[] words = {"greetings", "mountain", "school", "horse", "program"};

        System.out.println("Would you like to play? y/n: ");
        String playAgain = input.nextLine();

        while (playAgain.equals("y")){
            int misses = 0;
            boolean solved = false;


            String word = words[r.nextInt(5)];
            char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
            char[] hiddenWordArray = Arrays.copyOf(wordArray, wordArray.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                hiddenWordArray[i]='*';
            }

            while (!solved){
                System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word ");
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(hiddenWordArray[i]);
                }

                System.out.println();
                char guess = input.next().charAt(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    if (guess==wordArray[i]){
                        hiddenWordArray[i]=guess;
                    } else if (guess!=wordArray[i]) {
                        misses++;
                    }
                }

                if (Arrays.equals(hiddenWordArray, wordArray)){
                    System.out.println("The word is: "+word+". You missed "+misses+" times");
                    solved = true;

                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y/n: ");
            playAgain = input.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you try to come up with a solution, try to think about it out loud without "programming syntax", first.

Meaning: what would you do in "real life", without a programming language?

In this example, a possible solution would be the following:

1. Let the player guess a character
2. Check every letter in the word for that character
3. If it matches, reveal that character in the word
4. *After* checking the entire word, if nothing matched, count it as a miss

And now you can translate the individual steps into the programming language.

You did points 1 to 3 just fine, so what you are currently struggling with is point 4. Note, that you would count the miss *after* checking the entire word, while in your solution you are doing it for every character. The second thing to observe is the phrase "if nothing matched", which indicates, that you need to remember, *if* something matched.

With all that you can, for example, come up with something like this:

```java
bool miss = true;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (guess == wordArray[i]){
        miss = false;
        hiddenWordArray[i]=guess;
    }
}
if (miss) misses++;
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (guess==wordArray[i]){
        hiddenWordArray[i]=guess;
    } else if (guess!=wordArray[i]) {
        misses++;
    }
}
```

Every letter different from input couse a `misses` incrementation, that's wrong. What we want is that char is not found in the entire `wordArray` than increment `misses`. It is done like this:

```
boolean found = false; // variable to store if there is at least 1 letter found
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (guess==wordArray[i]){
        hiddenWordArray[i]=guess;
        found = true; // store that there is at least 1 found
    }
}
if(!found){ // if not found, increment misses
    misses++;
}
```